# Make: Setting variable based on target

Tags: makefile

I want to set a variable depending on the assigned target.
For instance:

```
if target == filename_a then
  VAR1 = YES
if target == filename_b then
  VAR2 = YES
```

Obviously, this is pseudo-code and not proper make-syntax.

What I really want to do is to include different make-files and include-directories dependent on target. Some targets share the same settings, and hence it is easier to maintain in one makefile.

An example of what it will be used for later:

```
ifeq ($(VAR1), YES)
  include foo.mk
endif
ifeq ($(VAR2), YES)
  include baz.mk
endif
```

Unfortunantly the following syntax cannot be used:

```
target : VAR1 = YES
```

Since this variable assignment is only valid through the process of actually building target, as I understand it.

The target environment is ClearMake 7 under Solaris, so please avoid any GNU Make specific solutions.

Thanks

---

Edit:
As far as I can tell, make does not work in a way where the target is available during the processing step. Hence the feature asked for does most likely exist.

Comment: Tell us more about the include-file setup and naming. Why do you need to choose between multiple include-files, what variables are they ultimately defining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be surprised if this can work, since as I understand it, Make processes include statements *before* it knows what targets it needs to make.  But I know nothing about ClearMake and I'm not really an expert, so hopefully someone proves me wrong...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, you seem to be right. Thanks for the response though.